# Get SQL Column Value value from Nested Array

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

To explain this better here is my Code:

```
        $mydate=Carbon::now()->addHours(8);
        $newdate=$mydate->toDateString();

        $myquery = DB::table('attendances')->where('date_only', '=', $newdate)->orderBy('logon','asc')->get();

        $counter=0;
        foreach ($myquery as $newquery) 
        {
        $query1[$counter]=$newquery->user_id;

        $finalquery[$counter]= DB::table('employees')->where('id', '=', $query1[$counter])->get();
        $counter++;

        }

        var_dump($finalquery[2]);
```

The output of this code will be this:

```
      array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#160 (6) { ["id"]=> int(23) ["firstname"]=> string(3) "Kim" ["lastname"]=> string(7) "Samsung" ["position"]=> string(10) "Programmer" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2014-11-25 07:21:31" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2014-11-25 07:21:31" } }
```

What i want to do is to access one of its value so I tried this

```
         //I change
         var_dump($finalquery[2]);
         //to this
         var_dump($finalquery[2]->firstname);
```

But what I get is just error. Error Code 500

Comment: Looks like `$finalquery[2]` is an array... what does `var_dump($finalquery[2][0]->firstname);` render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   // not necessary
  foreach ($myquery as $key => $newquery) 
    {
        $query1[$key]=$newquery->user_id;
        $finalquery[$key]= DB::table('employees')->where('id', '=', $query1[$key])->get();
    }

    // necessary

    print_r($finalquery->toArray());  // if its array of objects I'm converting it into an array
        // or
    print_r($finalquery);
```

**Edit:**  buddy my suggestion is to use `joins` This single query will get you all the data need not use a `foreach` with several queries  [**Reference**](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins)

```
$myquery = DB::table('attendances')->select('employees.id as emp_id','attendances.id as att_id',/*your fields*/)
        ->leftJoin('employees', 'employees.id','=','attendances.id')
        ->where('date_only', '=', $newdate)
        ->orderBy('attendances.logon','asc')->get();


    print_r($myquery->toArray());
```

in controller

```
 return View::make('home', array('mydata' => $finalquery));
```

in view:  (for blade)

```
@if($mydata && count($mydata) > 0)
    @foreach($mydata as $data)

        {{ $data->id }}<br>
        {{ $data->name }}<br>
        {{ $data->etc }}<br>

    @endforeach
@else
    <p>sorry no data to display</p>
@endif
```

Comment: Sorry sir, I dont get this one, but I'm gonna be printing the each values of array in the views, any idea how? using foreach. ANyways thanks for the answer.

Comment: wait ill update... are you gonna us blade.php or normal php??

Comment: Yes sir and I use this code on my controller return View::make('home')->with('mydata',$finalquery); but im just getting error

Comment: I just dont unbderstand your answer with that just one query. I'm sorry newbie here. And also I get error when i used your last updated code

Comment: whats the error, mention the db table field names in the `select()` see the **Reference** mentioned

Comment: its an error 500 with this line  return View::make('home')->with(array('mydata' => $finalquery));

Comment: try `return View::make('home', array('mydata' => $finalquery));`

Answer (score 0):

Your `var_dump` suggests `finalquery[2]` is an array of objects, not an object itself. So this wont work

```
var_dump($finalquery[2]->firstname);
```

This will

```
var_dump($finalquery[2][0]->firstname);
```

Like

```
foreach($finalquery[2] as $obj)
{
      echo $obj->firstname;
}
```